# node async module.export undefined

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, fs

I have a file with an `async waterfall` 
this takes a directory, of JSON files, and combines them into a single object and exports the object for a second file to use

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var itemsDir = './data/';
var async = require('async');

function readDirectory(callback){
    console.log("reading directory");
    fs.readdir(itemsDir, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            callback(err);
        }
        console.log("calling back with directory array", files);
        return callback(null, files);
    });
}

function sortFiles(files,callback){
    console.log("sorting files", files);
    async.map(files, function(file, cb){
        console.log("sorting a single file, ", file);
        if(path.extname(file) === '.json'){         
            return cb(null,file);
        }   
    },
    function cb(err, results){
        console.log("returning files", files);
        callback(null, results);
    }); 
}

function buildItemList(jsonFiles, callback){
    console.log("building item list", jsonFiles);
    var itemList = {};
    jsonFiles.forEach(function(file){
        var data = require(itemsDir+file);  
        var keys = Object.keys(data);               
        itemList[keys] = data[keys[0]]; 
        console.log("building item list found data:", keys);        
    });     
    console.log("building item list returning data:", itemList);

    return callback(null, itemList);    
}

function getItemList(cb){
    async.waterfall([
            readDirectory,
            sortFiles,
            buildItemList
        ],
        function(err, results){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log("finished async function");
            cb(results);
        }
    );  
}

getItemList(function(results){
    console.log("exporting results", results);
    module.exports = results;
});
```

My issue is when I do `var items = require('filename.js')`

I am getting `{}` as a result from the `require` instead of an array of items

the first file is creating the object as expected and flows correctly just requiring it makes it empty

Comment: I changed the `return results` to `cb(results)` and now call `getItemList(function(results){ module.exports = results; });` but I am still getting output of `{}` when I `console.log(items)` in the second file

Comment: yes the log does display correct results, updated code

Comment: `module.exports.getItemList = function(cb) {
    async.waterfall([
        readDirectory,
        sortFiles,
        buildItemList
    ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("finished async function");
        cb(results);
    });
}

//  in other file
var items = require('filename.js');

items.getItemList(function(results) {
    var newarray = results;
});`

Comment: Thanks this worked, please add this as an answer if you wish

Comment: Added, glad it worked for you

Comment: Please marked answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that assignment to module.exports must be done immediately. It cannot be done in any callbacks.

```
module.exports.getItemList = function(cb) {
    async.waterfall([
        readDirectory,
        sortFiles,
        buildItemList
    ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("finished async function");
        cb(results);
    });
}

//  in other file
var items = require('filename.js');

items.getItemList(function(results) {
    var newarray = results;
});
```